# aws boto get extra data fields for volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

When using boto's get_all_volumes() method, the only field I am not able to retrieve - or rather, which is not available is the NAME field, which is specified after creation of the aws ebs volume.

[image]

I suppose the only way to provide a mapping between a user specified name and the volume id is to only create and attach volumes via boto, and store the name mappings in a database. Or is there another easy way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Name` value that appears in the console is actually the value of a tag called `Name`.  If you have tagged your volumes with this tag (or any tag) you can access those tags using the `tags` attribute of the `Volume` object.

```
import boto.ec2
c = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
volumes = c.get_all_volumes()
volume = volumes[0]
print(volume.tags)
```

The `tags` attribute is a dictionary containing all of the tags associated with the volume.  The `Name` tag, if you have assigned it, should show up there.